# Getting values(STRING) of ul into jquery variable

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have ul like this:

```
<ul class="options" id="selt_count">
  <li value="1">One</li>
  <li value="2">Two</li>
  <li value="5">Five</li>
  <li value="12">Other</li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" id="send1" value="send">
```

i used this script to get all values of li into variable in the following format (1,2,5,12) in jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#send1").click(function(){
            var values = $('#selt_count li').map(function() {
                return this.value
            });
            values;
            var s = '(' + values.get().join(',') + ')';
            alert (s);
        });
    });
</script>
```

But this script is not working if the values of li are given as character

Example: Now i have a ul:

```
<ul class="options" id="selt_count">
    <li value="jonh">One</li>
    <li value="jack">Two</li>
    <li value="black">Five</li>
    <li value="barbosa">Other</li>
</ul>
```

the script will display (0,0,0,0)

Can anyone please help me and tell me what is the error?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your HTML like this:

```
<ul class="options" id="selt_count">
    <li data-value="jonh">One</li>
    <li data-value="jack">Two</li>
    <li data-value="black">Five</li>
    <li data-value="barbosa">Other</li>
</ul>
```

And  JavaScript like this:

```
<script>
$('#selt_count li').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    var text = $(this).text();
    var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
    alert('Index is: ' + index + ' , text is ' + text + ' and value is ' + value);
});
</script>
```

more about `data-*` here: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

---

additional script based on your edits...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#send1").click(function(){
            var values = $('#selt_count li').map(function() {
                return $(this).attr('data-value');
            });
            var s = '(' + values.get().join(',') + ')';
            alert (s);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you please explain me why 'value' was not working and why 'data-value' worked?

Comment: `value` attribute is not meant to be with `<li>`... it's for form elements... as to why `data-value`, you can read the link I provided...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting text get the value attribute using `.attr()`.

```
var text = $(this).attr('value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of .index() is wrong. Check out the documentation: [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: var index = $('#selt_count li').index(this);

Answer (score 0):

Try [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/mU6MB/). This may help you.

with,

```
$('#selt_count li').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).attr('value');
    var text = $(this).text();
    alert('Index is: ' + index + ' and text is ' + text);
});
```